# Mapping data from one data structure to another

Tags: java, design-patterns, haskell, dictionary, functional-programming

I know that it is rather a common pattern in many programming languages (predominantly functional) but I don't know exactly how does it call. 
So I have one data structure e.g.  List A and other List B. List A contains some values (strings in Chinese) and I want to map this strings to List B translating them to English. The so called map and mutate. Can someone please tell how does this pattern named correctly and give some links to its implementation in objective-C , Java , Haskell, etc.

Comment: I answered, but then realized that I think you're asking something different to the question I answered. Can you give some clarification - for example, some example inputs together with the output you would expect?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Thank you! No no.  Your answer fully satisfy me. It is what i seek. I just thought it is called in some different way.
You can post your answer once again in order I can accept it.

Comment: Ah, okay. I've un-deleted it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This process is referred to as "mapping" or "map and mutate" (as you mentioned) and data types which can be mapped over can be instances of the `Functor` typeclass in Haskell (note that "functor" is used differently in C++). Additionally, in imperative languages, this process may be accomplished using a foreach-style loop.

### Functional languages

Many functional language provide a default implementation of `map` for lists, and may provide default implementations for other data types as well. For example, the Haskell implementation of mapping over lists is:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map _ []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs

chineseToEnglish :: [String] -> [String]
chineseToEnglish chineseStrings = map translate chineseStrings
```

More complex examples exist for more complex data structure. Try searching your favorite data structure on [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) and looking at the source.

### Imperative languages

While, in imperative languages, 3-element `for` loops provide the standard way to iterate over arrays, C++11, Java, and Obj-C all have more map-related `for` loops as well.

#### C++

C++11 provides an abstraction over iterators in its new ranged-for loop:

```
vector<string> chinese;
for (auto &s : chinese) {
    translate(s);
}
```

Extending the `iterator` class has been [explained elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839958/custom-iterator-in-c)

#### Java

Java provides a similar construct, but without automatic type inference or the need for explicit references:

```
ArrayList<LanguageString> chinese = new ArrayList();
for (LanguageString s : chinese) {
    s.translate();
}
```

Extending `Iterable` has also been [explained elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601658/java-how-to-implement-iterable).

#### Objective-C

I'm not as familiar with Obj-C as the others I've mentioned, but that subject appears to have been discussed thoroughly at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706153/iphone-objective-c-foreach-design-question).

Answer (score 3):

This pattern is generally called `map` or `apply` depending on the language. The example I'll use is turning the list of numbers [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] into their squares, [1, 4, 9, 16, 15].

In function al programming languages this is generally straightforward. For example, in Haskell

```
>> let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>> map (\x -> x^2) numbers
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

In R, which is a language with a function feel

```
>> numbers = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>> sapply(numbers, function(x) {x^2})
[1] 1  4  9 16 25
```

Or in Python

```
>> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>> map(lambda x: x**2, numbers)
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

In languages that don't support first-class functions, like Java, you generally use a loop for this:

```
int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] result  = new int[5];

for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
    result[i] = Math.pow(numbers[i], 2);
}
```